# Почему изображение (TImage) на форме не обновляется?

Tags: delphi

Создал форму с компонентом TImage. Передаю это изображение в свой класс, где на его Canvas-е рисую. Почему изображение на форме не обновляется? (Пробовал Image.picture.loadfromfile - то же самое.)

Comment: на Canvas е класса рисуете или формы

Comment: Потому что он для этого не предназначен. Используйте PaintBox, а в свой класс передавайте ссылку на его канву.

Comment: Рисую на канвасе Imag-а

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там есть хитрая функция перерисовки.

```
TImage.Repaint;
```

Для скорости работы я использовал буфер (TBitmap), помещал в него необходимое изображение:

```
BitBlt(myImage.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0,
     myBuffer.Width, buf.Height,
     myBuffer.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

И сразу после нее перерисовка.

Comment: спасибо, обязательно попробую.

Comment: а чем отличается Repaint от Refresh&

Comment: А вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251009/whats-the-difference-between-refresh-update-repaint stackoverflow подсказывает